# Doubt about the topological space of Measurable Functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

My teacher wrote this on the blackboard but I can't see why it's true or not.

> The vector space of (Lebesgue) measurable functions with the point-wise topology is a topological vector space which is closed.

I don't really get it, because in every topology, the whole set, is open and closed, so I thought he might have wanted to say **complete**. I don't know, I'm quite confused.

EDIT: I asked him what he meant, by email, and stated that he might've wanted to say ***sequentially closed*** but this was his answer:

> Consider the vector space of functions with domain on a measurable set, endowed with the point-wise convergence topology, then the subset of measurable ones is closed.

Comment: Maybe he meant that if a sequence of Lebesgue measurable function converges pointwise to some function, then the limiting function is also Lebesgue measurable, i,e; the space is closed under talking limit.

Comment: I've edited the question with the answer my teacher gave me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is rather controversial, because its most natural interpretation

> The space of Lebesgue measurable functions is a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ endowed with the product topology.

is **false** (provided we believe in non-measurable functions). In point of fact, the subset $S$ of all the functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, f(x)\ne 0\}$ has finite cardinality is already dense in that topology.

The second most natural guess would be

> The space of Lebesgue measurable functions is a *sequentially* closed subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ endowed with the product topology.

Which is, of course, true: the pointwise limit of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of Lebesgue measurable functions is Lebesgue measurable.

In my opinion, you may want to ask your teacher for clarifications.

Comment: I'll ask him, and if this is what he really means, I'll accept your answer. Thanks in advance!!